# Как плавно менять цвет у краев спрайта unity?

Tags: unity3d

Есть вот такой вот спрайт на сцене

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как я могу плавно менять цвет градиента по краям и так чтобы изменение цвета можно было запускать через код (допустим в игре что-то произошло и я посылаю сигнал сменить цвет)

Comment: например шейдером

Comment: а как именно это сделать

Comment: Я вечером напишу ответ про шейдер, если будет еще актуально

Comment: Спасибо, буду ждать

Comment: Спрайт - это чисто эти линии с градиентом или внутри просто черный цвет?

Comment: Внутри черный цвет

Comment: Color.RGBToHSV(); и изменение hue? не? по крайней мере так пишут на форуме юнити =)

Comment: А можно ссылку описание этого способа?

Comment: мне чтобы попробовать нужна текстура

Comment: куда вам её скинуть?